# Python Opencv - Cannot change pixel value of a picture

Tags: python, opencv, pixel

**Need to change the white pixels to black and black pixels to white of the picture given below**[image]

```
    import cv2

    img=cv2.imread("cvlogo.png")
```

A basic opencv logo with white background and resized the picture to a fixed known size

```
    img=cv2.resize(img, (300,300))#(width,height)


    row,col=0,0
    i=0
```

Now checking each pixel by its row and column positions with for loop

If pixel is white, then change it to black or if pixel is black,change it to white.

```
    for row in range(0,300,1):
        print(row)
        for col in range(0,300,1):
            print(col)
            if img[row,col] is [255,255,255] : #I have used == instead of 'is'..but there is no change 
                img[row,col]=[0,0,0]
            elif img[row,col] is [0,0,0]:
                img[row,col]=[255,255,255]
```

There is no error in execution but it is not changing the pixel values to black or white respectively. More over if statement is also not executing..Too much of confusion..

```
    cv2.imshow('img',img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is also a method of solving this problem.
CREDITS:ajlaj25

```
    import cv2


    img=cv2.imread("cvlogo.png")
    img=cv2.resize(img, (300,300))
    height, width, channels = img.shape

    print(height,width,channels)

    for x in range(0,width):
        for y in range(0,height):
            if img[x,y,0] == 255 and img[x,y,1] == 255 and img[x,y,2] == 255:            
                img[x,y,0] = 0
                img[x,y,1] = 0
                img[x,y,2] = 0

            elif img[x,y,0] == 0 and img[x,y,1] == 0 and img[x,y,2] == 0:
                img[x,y,0] = 255
                img[x,y,1] = 255
                img[x,y,2] = 255
```

> *img[x,y]* denotes the channel values - all three: *[ch1,ch2,ch3]* -
>   at the x,y coordinates. img[x,y,0] is the ch1 channel's value at x,y
>   coordinates. 
>               **
>
> x and y denotes pixels location not RGB values of pixel .So,
>   img[x,y,0] is the ch1 channel's value at x,y coordinates

**

```
    cv2.imshow('Coverted Image',img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 6):

I am not very experienced, but I would do it using numpy.where(), which is faster than the loops.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Read the image
original_image=cv2.imread("cvlogo.png")
# Not necessary. Make a copy to plot later
img=np.copy(original_image)

#Isolate the areas where the color is black(every channel=0) and white (every channel=255)
black=np.where((img[:,:,0]==0) & (img[:,:,1]==0) & (img[:,:,2]==0))
white=np.where((img[:,:,0]==255) & (img[:,:,1]==255) & (img[:,:,2]==255))

#Turn black pixels to white and vice versa
img[black]=(255,255,255)
img[white]=(0,0,0)

# Plot the images
fig=plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,2,1)
ax1.imshow(original_image)
ax1.set_title('Original Image')
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(1,2,2)
ax2.imshow(img)
ax2.set_title('Modified Image')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I think this should work. :)
(I used numpy just to get width and height values - you dont need this)

```
import cv2

img=cv2.imread("cvlogo.png")
img=cv2.resize(img, (300,300))
height, width, channels = img.shape

white = [255,255,255]
black = [0,0,0]

for x in range(0,width):
    for y in range(0,height):
        channels_xy = img[y,x]
        if all(channels_xy == white):    
            img[y,x] = black

        elif all(channels_xy == black):
            img[y,x] = white

cv2.imshow('img',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: well ! Its Working ! But can you spot the error in my code.

Comment: And what is this line denotes " _if img[x,y,0] == 255 and img[x,y,1] == 255 and img[x,y,2] == 255:_"

Comment: - I am not sure still new to python :D - but the problem with your code was that you never get inside your if condition. I think you can not test equality like you did (e.g.: [x, y, z] == [255, 255, 255]). I check equality for every channel separately. I hope that is the right answer.

Comment: img[x,y] denotes the channel values - all three: [ch1,ch2,ch3] - at the x,y coordinates. img[x,y,0] is the ch1 channel's value at x,y coordinates.

Comment: :) Thanks but I really cannot understand the concept of separating the channels .. if u can explain its helpful else share any link regarding this.

Comment: Now I can understand bro .. Thanks! wishes!

Comment: Numpy is not need here where img.shape is a class of cv2 module @ajlaj25

Comment: Oh, you are right!
So I read about this issue. If you are testing two arrays with more than one elements e.g.:
    x = np.array([1,2,3])
    y = np.array([1,4,5])
    x == y
it returns
    array([ True, False, False], dtype=bool)
and that is why we have any() and all().
if any( x==y) returns True, than one of the elements are equal.
if all( x==y ) returns True, than all of the elements are equal.
I hope its clear :) - I will edit the code!

Comment: Yup! I got the thing what u r saying! Well Understood!

Comment: Hello! Do u changed the answer? @ajlaj25  ...all(channels==color) represent all 3 channels right?

Answer (score 1):

A bit late, but I'd like to contribute with another approach to solve this situation. My approach is based on **image indexation**, which are faster than looping through the image as the approach used in the accept answer.

I did some time measurement of both codes to illustrate what I just said. Take a look at the code below:

```
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# Reading image to be used in the montage, this step is not important
original = cv2.imread('imgs/opencv.png')

# Starting time measurement
e1 = cv2.getTickCount()

# Reading the image
img = cv2.imread('imgs/opencv.png')

# Converting the image to grayscale
imgGray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Converting the grayscale image into a binary image to get the whole image
ret,imgBinAll = cv2.threshold(imgGray,175,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

# Converting the grayscale image into a binary image to get the text
ret,imgBinText = cv2.threshold(imgGray,5,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

# Changing white pixels from original image to black
img[imgBinAll == 255] = [0,0,0]

# Changing black pixels from original image to white
img[imgBinText == 0] = [255,255,255]

# Finishing time measurement
e2 = cv2.getTickCount()
t = (e2 - e1)/cv2.getTickFrequency()
print(f'Time spent in seconds: {t}')
```

At this point I stopped timing because the next step is just to plot the montage, the code follows:

```
# Plotting the image
plt.subplot(1,5,1),plt.imshow(original)
plt.title('original')
plt.xticks([]),plt.yticks([])
plt.subplot(1,5,2),plt.imshow(imgGray,'gray')
plt.title('grayscale')
plt.xticks([]),plt.yticks([])
plt.subplot(1,5,3),plt.imshow(imgBinAll,'gray')
plt.title('binary - all')
plt.xticks([]),plt.yticks([])
plt.subplot(1,5,4),plt.imshow(imgBinText,'gray')
plt.title('binary - text')
plt.xticks([]),plt.yticks([])
plt.subplot(1,5,5),plt.imshow(img,'gray')
plt.title('final result')
plt.xticks([]),plt.yticks([])
plt.show()
```

That is the final result:

[Montage showing all steps of the proposed approach](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ieZqW.png)

And this is the time consumed (printed in the console):

```
Time spent in seconds: 0.008526025
```

In order to compare both approaches I commented the line where the image is resized. Also, I stopped timing before the `imshow` command. These were the results:

```
Time spent in seconds: 1.837972522
```

[Final result of the looping approach](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ujlh.png)

If you examine both images you'll see some contour differences. Sometimes when you are working with image processing, efficiency is key. Therefore, it is a good idea to save time where it is possible. This approach can be adapted for different situations, take a look at the [threshold documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.0/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html).